# Excel 2013 VBA ThisWorkBook BeforeClose event not recognizing methods

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a WorkBook_BeforeClose event in the ThisWorkbook module of my workbook that removes all validation dropdowns and resets all filters on every page.

When I try to close the workbook, this code runs:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

   Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In Worksheets

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Delete
        .ShowAllData

    Next

End Sub
```

and I get a 'Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference' with ".SpecialCells" highlighted.  If I comment out that line, I get the same error with '.ShowAllData' highlighted.

I've checked the spelling and syntax against multiple web references, and it all seems valid.  What have I done wrong or omitted?

Comment: It is just what the error says; you have an unqualified reference. Typically you can only use unqualified references (references beginning with a `.`) in a `With` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You don't have a `With` bloc so you cannot use a dot `.` without explicit qualification to an object

2- `SpecialCells` is not a member of `Worksheet` but of `Range`, so you need to call it on the `Cells` object of the worksheet.

3- to remove the validation but keep the cells' values, you need to delete the validation but not the range itself

4- check the `AutofilterMode` prior to removing the filtering, and use `.autofilter` with no arguments to remove it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.Cells.AutoFilter ' <-- remove autofilters
    ws.Cells.Validation.Delete ' <-- removes validation, not the content
  Next
End Sub
```

5- Finally, the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event might not be the appropriate event for your task, because the changes (validation and autofilters removed) will not necessarily be saved. You might consider using instead the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.